# How to pass a parameter of a lambda functon to another function which accepts the lambda function as parameter

Tags: python, lambda

I am using a function (more specifically *optim.lr_scheduler.LambdaLR* from torch) where a Lambda function is passed as parameter.

```
from torch import optim

lambda1 = lambda epoch: epoch /10
optimizer = optim.SGD(model.parameters(), lr=0.1)
scheduler = optim.lr_scheduler.LambdaLR(optimizer, lr_lambda=lambda1)
```

As long as the lambda function is simple I can handle it fine. But I found myself in need of using a normal function instead and I passed the function name as parameter.

```
def func1(epoch, base=10):
  return epoch/base

scheduler = optim.lr_scheduler.LambdaLR(optimizer, lr_lambda=func1)
```

which does the same thing exactly as the lambda function above but it can be more easily expanded to a complex function (as I needed it to be). The problem is I do not know how to actually pass the parameter (*base* in this case) to the function (*optim.lr_scheduler.LambdaLR* in this case) accepting the lambda function.

Is there a way to pass this parameter, in other words to pass *base* to *optim.lr_scheduler.LambdaLR* through *func1*?

Comment: Is this what you mean: `lr_lambda=lambda epoch: func1(epoch, mybase)`, where `mybase` is defined somewhere else?

Comment: Define a factory function: `def fact_fn(base=10): return lambda epoch, base=base: epoch / base`. Then you can do: `lr_lambda=fact_fn(base=16)`. This is more or less the same as what [functools.partial](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial) does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, inspired by @ekhumoro's comment I made a factory function which takes as argument just the parameters I want to control (in this case just `base` and not `x` I mean).

Edit:
made some adjustment to get the desired function with the correct parameters (as @Lourenço commented).

```
def get_func1(base=10):
  def func1(epoch, base=base):
    return epoch/base
  return func1

func1 = get_func1(base=20)
scheduler = optim.lr_scheduler.LambdaLR(optimizer, lr_lambda=func1)
```

So, the idea is that now the returned `func1` function inside `get_func1` function has the correct parameter for `base` (and, thus, potentially be more complex with messing with the peculiarities of being a lambda function) while on the same time I can pass it by solely its name (now it should be `get_func1`) and be used in the place of lambda function.

Comment: What you have there does not follow @ekhumoro's comment. By passing just the name of `get_func1` you will be using get_func(base=epoch) and get the corresponding `func1` instead of the desired learning rate. either use `lr_lambda=get_func1()` to use the default base value, or `lr_lambda=get_func1(value)` to change the base value. This way lr_lambda will be the desired `func1` and you will get proper learning rates.

Comment: You are probably right on this one. I used a stripped down version of the actual code and thus this error occurred.